# How to convert youtube video url to emded code for display video on our site?

Tags: php, html, regex, youtube

I am newcomer for displaying the videos on website. and i want to display movie video on our website but this movie embed code  has been disable so i can not copy embed video code.

Movie Video Url-   `https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=MFjSVGsYXLs`

and i am usinf iframe to display this movie like

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=MFjSVGsYXLs"></iframe>
```

Please hepl me..........

thanks

Comment: That's an easy string concatenation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/v/UNIQUE_ID?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Just replace **UNIQUE_ID** with `MFjSVGsYXLs`.

As for regex , this one should get the last string after `&v=`:

```
[^&v=]+$
```

Comment: i am sharing with you our website page url----http://nearestdukaan.com/index.php/moviesdukaan/EnjoyMovie/48

Comment: It seems that your page still has the old code. Check my updated answer (instead of `emebed/` use `v/`)

Comment: Looked at this video on Youtube , on the `share` -> `embed` window it clearly says that the uploader disabled the option of embedding this video - There's no legal solution in this case.

Comment: i have read this already,,, Please can u give alternate solution of it

Comment: Negative. as mentioned - no legal alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, If the videos owner has disabled embed code option then you wont be able to use an embed code, not even the API will give access. Users will only be able to view the video on youtube.

See: http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFjSVGsYXLs&format=json

**401 Unauthorized**

> The specified URL contains a private (non-public) resource. The
>   consumer should provide a link directly to the resource instead of any
>   embedding any extra information, and rely on the provider to provide
>   access control. [Source](http://oembed.com)